# Unable to connect to Oracle 9 (Powerbuilder 12.5) - ORA-12154 error

Tags: powerbuilder, oracle9i

after 10+ hours of trying I'd like to ask for your help.

I'm trying to connect to Oracle database "O90 Oracle 9i" in Powerbuilder 12.5.

My machine is a little bit messy regarding Oracle (I had couple if instances
and I'm not able to perfectly remove them) so I set up a Virtual Machine to test
it in clean environment.

That's what I do on the clean machine:

1. Installed Powerbuilder 12.5
2. Installed ERP software (where I try to connect).
   The ERP software distribution comes with \dbms\oracle\bin|network folders.
3. Added "C:\facterp\dbms\oracle\bin" (one of the folders from point 2) to PATH variable

Now I'm able to connect to server with SQLTools (apparently it reads data from tnsnames.ora located
in one of the folders from point 2).
Inside the tnsnames.ora:

GERP_POLAND =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS_LIST =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server.ip.given.here)(PORT = 1521))
)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVICE_NAME = orcl)

However when trying to connect from Powerbuilder I get an error ORA-12154.

I thought that maybe PB uses a different tnsnames.ora file (if I remove or modify
the file the error is the same). However there is no other file. From what I know
Powerbuilder uses ORACLE_HOME variable for tnsnames.ora location. I added the variable
but the issue remains the same.

My questions:

1. Can it be a 32bit vs 64bit issue? I know I should install 32bit Oracle client
   to work with 32bit PB but I don't install any client in this case. I just use provided
   files. That's enough for SQLTools but not for PB.
2. The TNS includes a line:
   (SERVICE_NAME = orcl).
   Does that mean I need to configure and use listener.ora?

I admit I haven't figured out the whole concept of different ways of connecting yet
(flat ora file/services/ect.)

Exactly the same happens on my "messy" machine.

I'll very gretefull for showing me the direction here.

Thank you,

Kris.

---

An update:

I expanded the ORACLE_HOME variable from:

C:\facterp\dbms\oracle

to

C:\facterp\dbms\oracle\network\admin\oracle

Now Powerbuilder connects to the database but when I expand the "tables"
treeview there are no tables. When I expand the "users" treeview it crashes
whole application.

It seems logical that the change I implemented (longer ORACLE_HOME path)
shouldn't work - there are some  ORACLE_HOME% references in other places...

Answer (score 0):

`ORA-12154` usually means that TNSNAMES.ORA doesn't contain database you're connecting to, or that tool you use can't locate TNSNAMES.ORA.

Try to create the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable which points to directory which contains TNSNAMES.ORA file. For example, on my PC, I set it as

```
TNS_ADMIN=C:\0_Oracle_library
```

Every Oracle software will now know where to look at. Because, each of them contains its own `\network\admin` or similar directory which has its own TNSNAMES.ORA. Whenever you add a new database, you have to maintain ALL of those TNSNAMES.ORA files (which becomes tedious). But, with `TNS_ADMIN`, you maintain ONLY ONE copy of that file and - no problem.

So, try it. It doesn't have to be a new directory, you can use existing one, such as

```
TNS_ADMIN=C:\facterp\dbms\oracle\bin
```

(or wherever your TNSNAMES.ORA file is).

Comment: Another newbie question from my side: do I have to see a specific service name in windows services to be able to connect? If yes should it be equal to a specific field in tnsnames.ora?

Comment: If Oracle database is installed on your PC, then its name is something like "OracleServiceXE" (like my Express Edition database). Startup "OracleXETNS**Listener**" as well. Its (service's) name doesn't have to be equal to what you have in TNSNAMES.ORA; that file contains "aliases" to your databases, and you can name that alias the way you want (e.g. "my_database", "home_xe", ...). But info - contained in TNSNAMES.ORA (host, port, service name) **must** reflect real data which is related to that database.

Comment: OK, my setup is now like yours - I have the same service name and listener name (both services running). The service name in tnsnames.ora is "orcl". Shouldn't I let the 10gXE instance know what database I'm connecting to? (providing "server.ip.given.here/orcl" + user name and password?).

Comment: I don't know PowerBuilder, never used it. But, any other tool I used to connect to an Oracle database expected database alias (from TNSNAMES.ORA), username and password. Or, you can use connect string you suggested, for example `db_server:port/service_name username/password`

Comment: I'm connecting from "Database profile Setup" in PB so I'm filling the fields. I'm still not sure what's the connection between the data I provide in PB (Server: 10.100.100.10\orcl), the Oracle 10g instance and tnsnames.ora. You mentioned that service name in TNSNAMES.ORA should refletect real database information. Is it "orcl" in my case or OracleServiceXE? Please bear with me for some more time, I think we are getting to the solution :)

Comment: Service name is ORCL.

Comment: If PB still says "ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified" what "connect identifier" it means? "10.100.241.13\orcl"? My tnsnames.ora: GERP_POLAND =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.100.241.13)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

Comment: If I were connecting to your database using SQLPlus, I'd run `sqlplus scott/tiger@10.100.241.13:1521/orcl` (scott is username, tiger is its password). What I posted is a complete "connect string". If you have a database - and yes, you do - try to do what I posted right now: open command prompt and copy/paste `sqlplus...` and see whether it succeeds. It *should*.

Comment: I was able to connect following your instructions (message: "Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production")

Comment: Good. Now try to apply that to PowerBuilder. As I said, I don't use it so I can't tell you *what* to put *where*.

Comment: Still the issue. Another question: do I need to use listener.ora and sqlnet.ora?

Comment: I keep them in the same directory as TNSNAMES.ORA (the one TNS_ADMIN points to). Database is up and running - as you managed to connect. As if PowerBuilder has some issues, and I don't know what to do about it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that I already tried adding the TNS_ADMIN variable. Without any change.

However there is clearly something I'm missing:

In Powerbuilder when attempting the connection I provide:

```
*profile name* (probably has not meaning for this conversation, just internal name)
*server*: server.ip.given.here/orcl
*login&password*
```

I can't see anything that Oracle should look for in tnsnames.ora file. Should it look for "**GERP_POLAND**" from the tnsnames.ora below? If yes I can't see any reference to it in my connection atempts.

**GERP_POLAND** = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server.ip.given.here)(PORT = 1521)) ) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)

If I modify the server.ip.given.here/orcl to server.ip.given.here/orclblabla I get the same result (seems like it's connected - green check sign) but it's not connected.

By the way - using the PowerBuilder tracking information:

SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE FROM SYS.ALL_CATALOG --> empty result SELECT USERNAME FROM SYS.ALL_USERS --> crash of the application

Anyway - I feel like I must be missing some basic stuff here...

Many thanks for your help.